# How can i wrap wordpress post content in custom div

Tags: wordpress, post, wrapper

How can i wrap the post content in custom div in my wordpress website?

This is from the `single.php` file :

```
<div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(''); // content ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(); // content pagination ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end entry -->
```

I can't just put div around `the_content()` function because i have some plugins (Related posts and social sharing plugins) that append content to the `the_content()` function so if i put DIV around the function it will not work like i want because it will wrap also the plugins content. How can i achieve this?

Any help/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter on `the_content`. Put this in your `function.php`.
Note that, the `add_filter` function has a parameter `priority`, check [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

```
function my_content($content) {
    global $post;
    return '<div class="myWrapper">'.$content.'</div>';
}

add_filter('the_content', 'my_content');
```

Comment: Unless this has a higher priority than the plugins in question, this will also wrap the plugin content in the `div`s.

Comment: `add_filter` function has a `priority` parameter.

Comment: Exactly, you should edit your question to reflect that...or else this may fail to actually answer the question. The correct `$priority` is key in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you a ton everyone, the filter function with priority solved my problem !